# Can I hide a user control in a master page from a content page?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, master-pages

How can I hide a user control on the master page from a content page? This is code I have on my content page's load.

```
    Dim banner As UserControl = DirectCast(Master.FindControl("uc_banner1"), UserControl)
    banner.Visible = True
```

Does nothing for me :(

Comment: You can, but you should not. A better approach would be "why is your design requiring you to go down this path?", and fix that. Pages & controls should not care about the contents of their master page(s), and vice-versa.

Comment: I have a weird dynamic banner that is loaded. I need it to show 3 on Default.aspx and 2 on all other pages. They are just <li> tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expose the visible property of the user control via a property of the `MasterPage`.

In your `MasterPage`:

```
public bool MyBannerVisibility
{
    get { return uc_banner1.Visible; }
    set { uc_banner1.Visible = value; }
}
```

Then make sure to add a reference in your content page:

```
<%@ MasterType TypeName="YourMasterPageTypeName" %>
```

Then in your content page just do:

```
Master.MyBannerVisibility = false;
```

**Edit:** Since your using VB.net I used a code converter to convert it for you:

```
Public Property MyBannerVisibility() As String
    Get
        Return uc_banner1.Visible
    End Get
    Set
        uc_banner1.Visible = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Content Page:

```
Master.MyBannerVisibility = False
```

Comment: My MasterPage name is 'Site.Master' I only need to put 'Site' in the reference on the content page correct?

Comment: @Landmine No you should just need `this.Master` (not sure what you mean by `Site.Master`. The `MasterType` definition in your content page will set `this.Master` to refer to your specific MasterPage.

Comment: The file name for my master page is "Site.Master"